# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined by using Fetch with a Const

Tags: javascript, fetch, discord, discord.js

I want to make a Discord Bot that shows the Level in Rainbow Six Siege with a simple Command (!level). The problem is when I put in the link of the API (`https://r6tab.com/api/search.php?platform=uplay&search=B4A.AroPix`) it shows the Stats of my Account and everything works.

But I want the user to type his own Name (!level THISISMYUSERNAME) and he gets the level of his own account. But when I try using this I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

by using Fetch with a const.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const prefix = '!level';
    const level = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const command = level.shift;
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; {
        fetch(`https://r6tab.com/api/search.php?platform=uplay&search=${level}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => message.channel.send(`Dein Level ist: ${json.results[0].p_level}`));

    }
})
```

This is by the way only 1 Function of my Bot so if you need more Code just reply and i will send the whole Code.

Comment: Can you log out the "json" variable please?

Comment: a little bit weird your `if`, it returns then it opens bracket...

Comment: i think i dont have a json variable.

Comment: You might be worth reading: https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/first-bot/command-with-arguments.md

Comment: do you need any more help with this question? Please let me know or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should you JSON.parse(res) instead of res.json().

Comment: i get this: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: No, that part is right. `res.json()` returns a Promise that deserializes the response to JSON.

Comment: can you get here print screen of this new code and what "res" do you get?

Comment: and also my problem is not that it wont post the level my problem is that i cant use it with a constant like !level [USERNAME]

Comment: Sorry im new and i dont know how to print a screen but if i now replay i get this : SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
fetch('https://r6tab.com/api/search.php?platform=uplay&search=B4A.AroPix')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json.results[0].p_level))
```